# How to get data interface withing a struct class using Marshaling from C++ to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

i'm trying to read data in C# from C++.
this data is in a struct class. The struct class contain enums, managed types and and an interface like this :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Params
{
    public int Counter;
    public SensorType deviceType;
    //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
    public IntPtr IParams;
}
 public interface IParamsSensor
    {
        EnumA IMovement { get; set; }
        int IRange { get; set; }
        EnumB IMode { get; set; }
    }
  public enum SensorType
    {         
        SENSORA,
        SENSORB, 
    };
   public enum EnumA
    {         
        UP,
        DOWN, 
    };
   public enum EnumB
    {         
        WIRE,
        WIRELESS, 
    };
```

The same struct class in C++ :

```
typedef struct tagParams {
      int Count;
      SensorType deviceType;
      IParamsSensor* IParams;
     }Params;

class IParamsSensor
{
public:
    virtual ~IParamsSensor() {};

    virtual EnumB getMode() = 0;
    virtual EnumA getMouvement() = 0;
    virtual int getRange() = 0;

    virtual void setMode(const EnumB& m) = 0;
    virtual void setMouvement(const EnumA& d) = 0;
    virtual void setRange(const int& d) = 0;
};

class IParamsSensorA : IParamsSensor
{
    EnumB getMode(){return EnumB::WIRE;};
...
}
    enum SensorType
        {         
         SENSORA,
         SENSORB, 
        };
    enum EnumA
        {         
         UP,
         DOWN, 
        };
    enum EnumB
        {         
         WIRE,
         WIRELESS, 
        };
```

the code in C# to get the data is like this :

```
byte[] value = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(SensorParams )];
IntPtr ptrArray = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(value.Length * sizeof(byte));
Array.Clear(value, 0, value.Length);
object objAsArrayOfDouble = value;
    
Marshal.Copy(ptrArray, value, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(SensorParams));   
short ret = pinvoke.Method(ref objAsArrayOfDouble);
    
byte[] scales = new byte[((byte[])objAsArrayOfDouble).Length];
Array.Clear(scales, 0, scales.Length);

SensorParams = ByteArrayToStructure<Params>(((byte[])objAsArrayOfDouble));
SensorParams.IParams //I want to get the data from this pointer
```

The goal is to get the C++ class "IParamsSensorA"  in my C# program using the "IParamsSensor" interface withing the "Params" (C# structure).
With PTrToStructure i get all the data but when it comes for the interface i only get some numbers with no sense.

any suggestions ?

Comment: I doubt that Properties are marshaled that easily. Tried it with simple fields instead?

Comment: i've already tought about this suggestion before. The problem is i cannot modify the source program in C++ where data come from. This is why i'm trying to find a way to get those data especially from the interface class "IParamsSensorA".

Comment: Then i don't see that this is possible. The memory layout for the struct/class/object should be data but you have getter/setter methods no data that can just be moved and interpreted accordingly on the CLR side. If you can't change the c++ part then think about wrapping that part with an additional layer of C++/CLR code and map the C++ structure to a fitting CLR structure yourself and then surface that to the actually C# code where you want to use it.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. 
Actually the c++ project doesn't support the C++/CLR configuration. It is an MFC dll with no CLR Support. That's why i only use Marshal and P/Invoke methods.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from creating a third project. C# talks to C++/CLR project and that project talks to the C++ project.

Comment: The creation of a third project with a CLR is considered to be a way to get the data for sure. However i don't have the rights to do that either. I'm looking for a way in my C# project.